# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

[Click to view data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCFOZ.png)I am trying to replace the `Item_Visibility` values with the `Item_Visibility` of each `Item_Identifier` (each item type). But it throws an error:

`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1`

```
data['Item_Visibilty'] = data.groupby('Item_Identifier').transform(
        lambda x: x.replace(x.mean()))
```

Comment: please include a data(as text) as an example to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve(5 rows should be enough)

Comment: I have added a sample of those two rows

Comment: No images please, post a sample data (not large) as text. Check [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also please do add how the output should look like, so we can compare ours. Thank you

Comment: @SreeramTP your solution throws new error:AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'todict'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood your question: you want to put the mean of `Item_Visibility` for each unique value of `Item_Identifier` into `Item_Visibility` column. I guess, `Item_Identifier`, in this case means a group of items because in other way it doesn't make sense to group them and then take the mean.

Answering you question:

```
# sample data creation
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4000,2),columns=['Item_Identifier','Item_Visibility'])
data.loc[:,'Item_Identifier']= data.loc[:,'Item_Identifier'].apply(
        lambda x: 'id1' if x> 0.4 else 'id2')
# creating map_table so we could map values
map_table = data.groupby('Item_Identifier').mean()
# mapping values
data.loc[:,'Item_Visibility'] = data.loc[:,'Item_Identifier'].map(
        map_table.to_dict()['Item_Visibility'])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: that helps please see the answer I found online. Isn't there any way to make this simple

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot table -

```
visibility_avg = data.pivot_table(values = 'Item_Visibility', index = 'Item_Identifier')
#imputing  0 values with mean visibility of products
miss_bool = data['Item_Visibility'].isnull()
data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Visibilty'] = data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: visibility_avg(x))
```